# Can I pass arguments to a kernel module in the kernel command line?

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel, driver

The pstore module receives an argument: https://github.com/stormbreaker-project/kernel_poco_citrus/blob/main/fs/pstore/platform.c#L546

```
int pstore_register(struct pstore_info *psi)
{
    struct module *owner = psi->owner;
```

and

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(pstore_register);
```

So, where are these arguments passed? Can I pass them in command line?

PS: I want to activate these flags: https://github.com/stormbreaker-project/kernel_poco_citrus/blob/main/fs/pstore/platform.c#L595

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.22/source/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.rst

Comment: @stark but how do I know the name of the flag `PSTORE_FLAGS_FTRACE`? Should the kernel command line be `pstore_register.PSTORE_FLAGS_FTRACE=1`?

Comment: When talk about Linux kernel, "arguments to a kernel module" are ones which defined by the module with `module_param` and similar macros. What you show is a **function** exported for use in other kernel files and in modules. Parameters to that function are defined by the **caller**. If a caller (module) fills the structure `psi` based on its arguments (created with `module_param`), then you could set these arguments in the command line. Otherwise for modify parameters passed you need to modify the caller's code.

Comment: You are confused between a predefined kernel module arguments and normal functions

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18-rc7/source/include/linux/pstore.h#L203  PSTORE_FLAGS_FTRACE is a macro, not a parameter.